# How do I detect the tap of a UIActionSheet button called inside a table view delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7, uiactionsheet

Ok I have a tableView with a UIActionSheet within it and there is no segue or anything a long those lines. A user has the option to swipe and delete a row or another option to take the user represented by a row a offline again.

When a user swipes they can delete the row.
When a user taps a UIActionsheet pops up with the option to "Take Offline" (destructive button) or cancel.

[image]

This is all wrapped in a tableView delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath row]);

    Person *person = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Need to edit %@'s info?", person.name]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Take Offline"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
   [popup showInView:tableView];
   [popup addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];


     [people removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I would normally use a UIActionSheetDelegate method to detect the tap of a button.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was clicked");
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is when I tap a row in my table the object is removed from the array and the table is reloaded instantly.

I don't want this to happen until the "Take Offline" button is clicked but can't figure out a way to do this. I've tried a future such as storing objects in instance variables and accessing them from other methods and trying to execute the code out of the tableView method but keep confusing myself.

What is the best way to do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a blog post about how to (and why) add block callbacks to alert views, action sheets and animations:

http://blog.innovattic.com/uikitblocks/

Using this approach you don't have to use a delegate and can instead rewrite your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath row]);

    Person *person = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Need to edit %@'s info?", person.name]
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Take Offline"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [popup setHandler:^(UIActionSheet *sheet, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
        [people removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView reloadData];
    } forButtonAtIndex:[popup destructiveButtonIndex]];

    [popup showInView:tableView];
}
```

You can download the source files for this from GitHub:

https://github.com/Innovattic/UIKit-Blocks

Comment: Hi this code does not work for me. I'm getting no visible interface for UIActionSheet at the block opening line. Also the popup instance shows errors until I add delegate:nil after initWithTitle

Comment: You will need to add the source files for the category that adds this functionality to your project. As mentioned in my answer you can download it from GitHub: https://github.com/Innovattic/UIKit-Blocks
After that, don't forget to add `#include "UIActionSheet+IABlocks.h"` to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're on the right line with the approach you say you've tried.

You'll need to keep a reference to the selected `Person` in a property. Declare a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *selectedPerson;
```

And store the selected person in this property in your `didSelectRow...` method. Then, use the UIActionSheetDelegate method to determine which button the user clicked. If they clicked 'Take Offline', then remove the person you stored in the `selectedPerson` property from the `people` array.

Comment: Works perfectly. Why did I declare strong? When is it finally destroyed? I just want to clarify this.

Comment: Cool. No problem - when you declare a `strong` property, it means that you are keeping a strong reference to the object, and that even if you are the last thing keeping a reference to it, it will be kept around instead of being deallocated.

Comment: So will ARC still take care of deallocating it?

Comment: Yep ARC will still take care of that for you (when there are no strong pointers left to that object).